# Scraping staff total by name in adjacent column using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Ok, this site is really messed up, you can tell it was written by the government.

There is a table within a table within a table that I need to access for a total staff count.

This is the method I wrote for the student count side modified for the staff when I discovered that it wasn't like the first page in that there was a single table.  The below code won't work because it's just looking at the top table.

```
    private int GetStaff(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        int nStaffCount = 0;
        foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")) 
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
            {
                HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("th|td");

                if (cells == null)
                    continue;
                foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells)
                {
                    if (cell.InnerText.ToLower() == "total staff (fte):")
                    {
                        //tbResults.Text += cell.InnerText + " " + cells[3].InnerText;
                        int.TryParse(cells[3].InnerText.Replace(",", ""), out nStaffCount);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return nStaffCount;
    }
```

The html code on the page looks like this:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td><img border="0" src="/ccd/commonfiles/images/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1"></td>
            <td>
            <b>Total Staff</b> <font face="arial" size="1">(FTE)</font>: 1026.25
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

The actual HTML code is so convoluted and big for what it does that it doesn't make sense to copy and paste the whole thing.  This is the link to the whole page: [problem page example here](https://nces.ed.gov/ccd/districtsearch/district_detail.asp?Search=1&InstName=new%20york&State=36&DistrictType=1&DistrictType=2&DistrictType=3&DistrictType=4&DistrictType=5&DistrictType=6&DistrictType=7&DistrictType=8&NumOfStudentsRange=more&NumOfSchoolsRange=more&ID2=3600076&details=2)

There are no classes, no id's. And again, this table exists in another table which exists in another table.  Why they did it like that, I have no idea.  It's frustrating as heck.  I've got zero ability to request they add in id's.

All I want to do is get to the 1026.25 value after "total staff"

Is there a way to select a row within the table, within the table, within the table by the text in that cell?  Or is there an easier way to get at that value?